# Running a command from apache user as ec2-user

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, sudo

I'm trying to run the following command

```
/usr/bin/ocr 1.pdf 1.xml
```

from Apache, but unfortunately this command only works with ec2-user. So I've tried to edit my PHP file to make it run like that:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u ec2-user /usr/bin/ocr 1.pdf 1.xml
```

But I got the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

So I've added the following line to /etc/sudoers

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u ec2-user /usr/bin/ocr
```

But I still have the same error.

The only thing that worked was:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But if I'm right, it allows apache to run any command with sudo, so it's a major security breach.

Do you have any idea of how I could do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
apache ALL=(ec2-user) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ocr
```